# Symfony 3 FOSJsRoutingBundle dev error

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm trying to use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) in my symfony project. 
It works perfectly in production mode, but in the dev mode I've got an error.

The problem is for this script link:

```
<script src="/lacapa/web/app_dev.php/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData"></script>
```

When I click on the link, I can see an error page which say:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong. Call to a member function
>   getUser() on null in UserCreatedListener.php

I don't understand why I get that.

Comment: Did you try clear cache?

Comment: Yes and still not work

Answer (score 0):

The FOSJsRoutingBundle is not compatible with Symfony3+ currently.